# Can anyone suggest any good texts on Green's functions in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

I am currently learning about Green's functions and want to write an essay on their use in quantum mechanics as part of an assessment.

I have seen that they can be used in describing the probability of a particle travelling from one place to another and are often called "propagators".

If anyone could suggest a good texts that may help me look deeper then I would be very grateful (I am a second year undergraduate).

Comment: Byron and Fuller has quite a large chapter on Green's functions including their use in QM.

Comment: Fetter-Walecka is my favourite. It is not super easy though.